# Enabling Acceleration tab on VirtualBox Manager running on Ubuntu 12.04 (guest OS)

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

1. I have a windows 7 host OS.  HW Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
2. On Oracle VM VirtualBox added a Ubuntu 12.04 Guest OS.  Configured it as 64 bit.  Note:  The System->Acceleration is enabled and "Enable VT-x/AMD-V" is enabled.  Also the other Nested Paging one.
3. Booted 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 guest OS.  The booting went fine.
4. Now, for some multiple system installation purposes, I need Oracle VM VirtualBox in the Ubuntu 12.04 Guest OS.  Installed the virtualbox and the addons.
5. Now in the Guest OS virtualbox System->Acceleration is not enabled. 
   Can anyone suggest how we could get the Acceleration enabled on the Oracle VM VirtualBox running on guest OS (ubuntu 12.04).  Please note Oracle VM VirtualBox is running on a guest ubuntu OS.

Comment: You need to have a virtual machine running inside a virtual machine?  This seems a bit redundant, and perhaps not an entirely good idea.

Comment: Yes this is for some test purpose.  Especially OpenStack.  I do not want to mess with my host OS.

Comment: @ Charles: Or rather some of the distributions I am trying is not ready for windows.  Hence trying them on guest OS.

Comment: I agree with @CharlesGreen running a VM in a VM will result in poor performance at best.

Comment: @Elder:  As i mentioned some of the distribution are not there on Windows and I need this hack to bring the system(s) quickly in.  Else only way bring cygwin on windows and trying (which I am doing as well).  If this is resolved then my task is quickly done.

Comment: At present Virtual Box does not expose VT-x/AMD-V to the guest OS. There are not much more than plans to sometimes enable this (see [#4032](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032)).

Comment: There is a thread in another virtualization engine, VMWare, which seems to indicate that they might be able to do this.  The link is at https://communities.vmware.com/message/2381655

Answer (score 0):

Try installing kernel compilated for guest os systems... on guest OS.... and install the feautures packs in Windows Host....

the support for

```
Enable VT-x/AMD-V
```

depend of the feautures in Host, and properly drivers.